# How do I create this matrix on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I am trying to create a matrix (32 x 32) with -1 on its main diagonal and 1 in its first and second superdiagonals. 0 everywhere else.

```
A = eye(32)* -1;
```

That gives me a matrix with -1 on its main diagonal, how do I proceed?

Comment: Umm... For a moment I saw an "accept" checkmark appear near my answer, but just before I accidentally clicked on it, then it was gone. Did you accept-unaccept my answer? Did you just accept it, and there's a major bug in the system? I'm not trying to be needy, I'm just surprised by what I saw:)

Comment: @AndrasDeak Accept is now back.  Good work!

Comment: Thanks @rayryeng but my question still stands. Is this a weird (and dangerous) bug, or did darkkkk7 remove the accept themselves?

Comment: @AndrasDeak They temporarily unaccepted it.  I saw his/her rep go down by 2 points in the interim.  I think your ping made the OP accept the answer again.

Comment: @rayryeng Ah, OK then, thank you both:)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
n=32;
toeplitz([-1; zeros(n-1,1)],[-1 1 1 zeros(1,n-3)])
```

is what you need. This will create a non-symmetric Toeplitz matrix (a band matrix), the first column of which is given by `[-1; zeros(32-1,1)]`, the first row by `[-1 1 1 zeros(1,32-3)]`. You could also define a function with size `n` as input parameter, if necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`spdiags`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) to set the diagonals directly into a sparse matrix and `full`-it if desired.

```
n       = 32;
Asparse = spdiags(ones(n,1)*[-1,1,1],[0,1,2],n,n);
Afull   = full(Asparse);
```

Answer (score 5):

```
n = 32
A = -1*eye(n); %Create 32x32 Identity
A(n+1:n+1:n^2) = 1; %Set 1st Superdiagonal to 1
A(2*n+1:n+1:n^2) = 1; %Set 2nd Superdiagonal to 1
```

Note that MATLAB uses [column-major order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row-major_order#Column-major_order) for matrices. For the 1st superdiagonal, we start with the (n+1)th element and choose every (n+1)th element thereon. We do a similar operation for 2nd superdiagonal except we start from (2*n+1)th element.

Comment: Since the matrix is square, it might make sense (and possibly be slightly faster) to use `A(n+1:n+1:end) = 1;` and `A(2*n+1:n+1:end) = 1;`. I wouldn't be surprised if this answer was the fastest in many cases.

Answer (score 5):

Just using [`diag`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html) and `eye`:

```
n = 32;
z = ones(n-1,1);
A = diag(z,1)+diag(z(1:n-2),2)-eye(n);
```

There's also:

```
n = 32;
A = gallery('triw',n,1,2)-2*eye(n)
```

using the [`gallery`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html) function with the [`'triw'`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gallery.html?#zmw57dd0e264708) option.

Comment: This one is not an upper diagonal matrix, not a tridiagonal one.

Comment: Wrong daigonal, question asked for 1 and 2, not -1 and 1. But I did not downvote.

Comment: @AndrasDeak: I see. Fixed. I though the OP was talking about the diagonals above and below.

Comment: Sure. I didn't downvote, mind you, just indicated the problem:)

Answer (score 4):

`diag` allows you to create a matrix passing a diagonal:

```
-diag(ones(n,1),0)+diag(ones(n-1,1),1)+diag(ones(n-2,1),2)
```

Last parameter 0 for the main diagonal, 1 and 2 for the super diagonals.

Answer (score 3):

If I can suggest more esoteric code, first create a vector full of 1s, then create the identity matrix, then shift create a diagonal matrix with these 1s with the vector and shift it to the right by 1, decreasing the amount of elements in the vector, then do it again for the last superdiagonal.

```
n = 32;
vec = ones(n,1);
out = -eye(n) + diag(vec(1:end-1),1) + diag(vec(1:end-2),2);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
N = 32;
A = -diag(ones(N,1)); % diagonal
tmp1=diag(ones(N-1,1),1); %1st supra
tmp1=diag(ones(N-2,1),2); @2nd supra
A = A+tmp1+tmp2;
```

using [`diag`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diag.html)

Comment: That does not provide the described output.

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach: this uses [`convmtx`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/convmtx.html) from the Signal Processing Toolbox:

```
n = 32; %// matrix size
v = [-1 1 1]; %// vector with values
M = convmtx(v, n);
M = M(:,1:end-numel(v)+1);
```